# Module Names Not Deleting Properly

Tags: screeps

This is probably more of a bug report than a question, but for me, if I delete a module, it is impossible to create a new module with the same name...

Comment: what browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be an issue with your `localStorage`, the game developer has answered a similar question regarding saving modules: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27060388/1814415

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely the case, as this shows in my localstorage:

```
"modules": {
    "main": "stuff",
    "harvester": null,
    "harvesters": null,
    "harvest": "stuff",
    "builder": null,
    "factory": null,
    "healer": null
}
```

Where the null values are old deleted modules. Obviously the localstorage module names need to be removed when removed in the UI as well, but it's not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of issues with Internet Explorer 11, if you're not using Chrome you can try that.  It seems like they've done all their testing in Chrome and left the other browsers out there to die.

Comment: Are you up to date?  That should be automatic but you never know... In Chrome 39.blah.blah.blah that works fine for me