# Screeps score/modules got reset

Tags: screeps

Yesterday I had a score of 1800 on the first map and now there is no more score. How could it be that this score was deleted? Furthermore, my scripts/modules were also deleted (I luckily saved them locally). Does it depend on cookies or something; what happened?

Answer (score 2):

In Simulation Room, your modules and scores are stored in browser `localStorage`. You may be using another browser or another anonymous browser session.

Comment: Same browser actually, no changes. Maybe some issue with my localStorage.

Comment: I had the same 'problem'. It does not get saved for longer then x-hours I assume

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing when I went to http://www.screeps.com instead of http://screeps.com, notice the www part. these 2 store your data in different locations.